# Are you joining the SDL Spring Hackathon?

Tags: discussion, innovate

Did you miss the Innovate 2015 Hackathon? No problem. You are now free to enter the competition online. Here is what you need to do to enter:

1. Join the SDL Community at [community.sdl.com](https://community.sdl.com)
2. Go to [SDL Hackathon group](https://community.sdl.com/developers/sdl_innovate_2015_spring_hackathon/w/teams) inside the community and join that group
3. Form a team of max 3 people and come up with a good team name
4. Clearly identify your team members, They all need to be member of the SDL Community
5. Please read [the rules](https://community.sdl.com/developers/sdl_innovate_2015_spring_hackathon/w/teams/683.hackathon-rules) of the competition
6. Enter a team page with your proposal under [this section](https://community.sdl.com/developers/sdl_innovate_2015_spring_hackathon/w/teams)
7. Submit your proposal before End of Business June 12th on your teams page

A jury inside SDL will pick a winner within 14 days after June 12th. A small webconference may be requested with your team to explain your submission.

Comment: whats the last date for registration for teams/individuals? Also, can one individual be part of two or more teams for multiple projects?

Answer (score 1):

A few clarifications:

There is no real last date of registration other than the end date (June 12th), but the later you register, the less time you have to work on your project, since you should register first before you start working on it. We do not accept existing projects, unless they are modified during the event. That modification should be a substancial one, not the final touch to an existing project (that would also not score high on the innovative part of it of course).

An individual can only be part of a single team, which is 1-3 persons. As a team you can only submit a single proposal. It would be unfair to everybody else if we allow people to be part of multiple teams and thus submit multiple proposals, since that would give them more chance at the prizes.